# Is there a way to fake registry entry in C#?

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to execute an .exe file from my C# code. The .exe file requires some key to exist in the registry. Now I have two options: 
1. Either I can add the key, execute the file, and then delete what I added from registry. 
2. OR If possible, I can fake the key in registry so that .exe can execute and I don't have to modify the registry.

Can someone please tell me if #2 is possible? If not then is there any other better way to deal with this situation (perhapds undo changes I made from registry)? or do I have to stick with #1?

Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: how would you fake the windows registry? What you are describing is forcing the EXE to go down a different code path and not use the Windows API call to access the registry. This would require disassembling the code or modifying with some sort of HEX editor either of which are really outside the scope of this site more than likely.

Comment: How serious would it be if you added the key and then couldn't revert it?  Remember that your program could fail in that critical interval (unrecoverable RAM error, power failure, etc)

Comment: Sounds to be you left out the obvious one: add it to the registry, *don't* remove it, never have to mess with it again.  Typical job of an installer.

Answer (score 2):

Intercepting registry reads is not for the faint of heart and will almost certainly require several orders of magnitude more work than option 1.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a function for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724901.aspx), but it only affects the process which calls it.  So you would have to use DLL injection.  C# (or any type of managed code) would not be my choice for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* intercept the read, then start developing a driver in C/C++ that calls [CmRegisterCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541918.aspx) to hook system-wide calls and filter out the ones you need. But I think you'll **seriously regret** even starting the project... just go with option 1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically *possible* to intercept calls to the registry using something like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). However, the intercept code cannot be written in C# and must be in C++ (or C, I suppose). Not to mention, doing this in a robust manner is going to be a *lot* of work.

Comment: Detours isn't necessary, simple DLL injection is sufficient.